# mount + cifs + where in the win machine need to configure the password

Tags: linux, mount, windows, cifs

I want to use cifs against some windows server in order to copy files

```
[root@host ~]# mount -t cifs -o username=<share user>,password=<share password>,domain=example.com //WIN_PC_IP/<share name> /mnt
```

where in the windows machine I need to configure the  password ?

```
 mount -t cifs -v //$win_machine/hostlist /mnt -o user=file,pass=$pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password you must use is the password of the Windows account; on Windows the regular account password is used both for login and for access to the shares, unlike Samba on Linux which maintains its own database of passwords. So for example if I have a computer named `\\Trillion` on which there is a share named `\\Trillion\Files` to which user `Trillion\Markow` has access, you would need to give the password of `Trillion\Markow`.

Answer (score 0):

if the windows servers are in a domain environment, the username and password are set on the domain controller, and then you should assign the appropriate read/write permission of the share folder. Otherwise, create the local username/password on the local computer management console -> local users and groups -> create new user, set password and assign privilege to the share folder.